# Do I go faster as Xerath if I spam Locus of Power?

Tags: league-of-legends

Xerath's Locus of Power provides a speed buff for a short time after ending its effect, but it also takes a second or two to activate.  Do you make up for the distance that you could have run while casting?  Is it advantageous to spam this to cross the map quicker?

Comment: I can't speak to whether the 35% speed makes up for toggle on/off time, but the mana cost of this scheme would almost certainly make it not worth it.

Comment: @lilserf what mana cost?

Comment: lilserf - the ability has no mana cost. Instead, cooldown is the limiting factor.

Comment: Oh hell, I completely missed that. Is there a good site to see the nitty gritty numbers without firing up the client? leagueoflegends.com just has descriptions with no numbers on 'em.

Comment: @lilserf: The [LoL Wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/League_of_Legends_Wiki) is pretty good at keeping current.

Answer (score 3):

Locus of Power cannot be spammed due to its cooldown, and due to the channel time during the set up, it rarely, if ever, results in a actual increase in units/minute speed.

What you *can* do, in Dominion, is activate Locus of Power before clicking on the point. Since you're already rooted due to capture channeling, with this method you can get a small speed boost after capturing each point.

In general though, think of Locus of Power's speed boost as a "consolation" prize for rooting you - it shouldn't be the reason you use the ability - use it for the % Magic Penetration and range bonus.

Some numbers:

> Base Movement Speed - 315
>
> Movement Speed with Boots - 385
>
> Movement Speed with W buff - 493 (you lose ~2 to diminishing returns)
>
> Speed increase from W - 493 - 385 = 108
>
> Normal speed = 385 x 3.5 seconds = 1347 units
>
> 1.5 sec channel time + Activate W speed bonus for 2 sec bonus speed x 493 = 986 units

Comment: "Spamming" just meant to use it as often as possible, and the cooldown falls like a rock at higher ranks, but the cast time/buff time/buff speed % are all fixed, so there shouldn't be a "rarely", only a "it does" or "does not".  Regardless of the cooldown, each cycle either helped or didn't.

Comment: @NickT It's "rarely, **if ever**" not just "rarely".

Answer (score 0):

You spend 0.5 seconds rooted for a 35% boost for 2 seconds.  Assuming your unbuffed speed is *R* units/second, you'll move

> 0.5 seconds × 0 units/sec + 2 seconds × 135% × *R* units/second = **2.7 *R* units**.

while you could have ran normally for 2.5 seconds and have covered

> 2.5 seconds × *R* units/second = **2.5 *R* units**.

So given no diminishing returns (minimal unless stacking multiple buffs) and no lag, spamming <kbd>W</kbd> as much as possible will make you go faster, increasing your movement by 20% of your unbuffed run speed per cast.  If you spend any more than ~200 ms over the 0.5 s minimum root time, then it's a loss.